# Windows Phone Emulator: Error Missing or Invalid ROM Image.

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I installed Windows Phone SDK7.1 in my WIN7 machine. When I try to open the Windows Phone emulator from the Windows Phone SDK7.1, the emulator is opened as shown but I got the following Error that "Error: Invalid or Missing ROM Image. [image]

Please help me in solving the issue to make my win Phone emulator. My actual requirement here is to test the Web page in Windows Phone. Thanks in Advance For any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Emulator is Working in my system. Thanks a lot For the Help i found in Eric's Question  [see the link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197/wp7x-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?prof=required) .

What id did is very simple .I closed all the applications but browser(to see the instruction) and opened the Emulator as "Run As Administrator" then it works for me.